# Mysql: Select from parent table, only if child table has rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need your help,
How do I Select from a parent table, only if child table (another table that depends on id of parent table) has rows in php?

For instance:
I have `CATEGORY` table and `Items` table. Where `Category` is the parent table and contains `ct_id, ct_name`,  while `Items` is child table which contains `it_id, ct_id` (linked to parent table), `it_name`

**PS: I don't need to select items, but I need only Categories ONLY if there are items linked to this table.**

Thank you

Comment: that would be a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: @smith   can you give me an example please? How to use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `INNER JOIN` which only returns records when there is a match on both tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM Categories a INNER JOIN Items b on b.ct_id = a.ct_id
```

But it is more efficient to run a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM Categories 
WHERE ct_id IN (SELECT ct_id FROM Items);
```

This is because in the first example it has to match the entire table first and then strip out all the duplicates using the `DISTINCT` keyword. The second example avoids the duplication by scanning the child table first.

This is known as a `Semi Join`. See here for more: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/semi-joins.html